# Emacs, probing arbitrary keymap

Tags: emacs, elisp, key-bindings

`key-binding` probes keys in the currently active keymaps. For those keymaps, such as minibuffer ones, or `isearch-mode-map` which are restrictive and become inactive as soon as the user presses a key outside of a limited set of defined keys, I am not able to invoke `key-binding` without deactivating those keymaps.

How do I:

1. Determine which keymaps come into effect after invoking certain commands (for example, `isearch-mode-map` is set as the overriding-local-map by `isearch-forward-regexp`) in a way that does not involve analyzing source code. Is there a hook that I can use to track/log the state of a variable?
2. Probe keys in those keymaps. For example, to what is `RET` bound in `isearch-mode-map`?

My closest solution has been to bind this function:

```
(defun probe_keybinding  ()
  (interactive)
  (message (prin1-to-string (key-binding (read-key-sequence-vector "Enter key to probe"))))
)
```

to an uncommon key like 'S-f9' and invoke it when the keymaps in which I am interested are active (eg in the middle of a `find-file` in the minibuffer or a `eval-expression`). This does not always work, for example, `isearch-forward-regexp` exits as soon as a non-recognized key is entered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. There's no easy way to determine which keymaps will come into use in response to particular commands. Any function can call `(use-local-map ...)` whenever it likes, so the only way to be sure is to read the source code.

   Having said that, the Emacs code does follow conventions that make it possible to find the answer in many cases. If `foo-mode` has a keymap, then the keymap will usually be named `foo-mode-map`. You can see a list of variables with names ending in `-map` by running `M-x apropos RET -map$ RET`.
2. You can look up a key in a keymap with the function `lookup-key`. See "[Functions for Key Lookup](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Functions-for-Key-Lookup.html)" in the Emacs Lisp manual. So to find out what `RET` is bound to in `isearch-mode-map`, evaluate:

   ```
   (lookup-key isearch-mode-map (kbd "RET"))
     ===> isearch-exit
   ```

Comment: Although I've never done this, I suppose if I really wanted to solve (1), I could write an advice for all the functions that might change the state of the active keymaps, for example, `use-local-map` and `setq`, and from there log all the interesting changes.

Answer (score 2):

Another element of the answer is to look at individual keymaps. Unfortunately, if you just do `C-h v isearch-mode-map` (or any other keymap variable) you will see a Lisp expression that is not very readable.

Instead, you can use `describe-keymap`, from library [`help-fns+.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/help-fns%2b.el). It is bound to `C-h M-k`, and it shows you all of the (non-menu) keys bound in a keymap, in a human-readable way. More [description here](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/HelpPlus).

Comment: I did try to look at the 'isearch-mode-map' contents, but they were not very useful, and I was not even able to determine to what `RET` was bound. Maybe I will try the library, although Gareth's `lookup-key` suggestion should work well if I only need to probe a specific key.

Comment: You will find `help-fns+.el` helpful in general. I work a lot with both `isearch-mode-map` and all of the minibuffer keymaps, so even just `C-h M-k` is invaluable for me.